# How to add a folder to the favorite folder in "Files" in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, files

Using Ubuntu 22.04 I am trying to add the "Windows" folder to the favorite folders on the left (where you can see "Work", "Tools", "Music" and "Private"). When I try to drag and drop the "Windows" folder to the left I see a "New bookmark" text, but when I release the mouse key nothing happens. The folder is not added to the left list.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: If anything else fails, you can directly edit the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` with a text editor to add / remove bookmarks.

Comment: Ah cool, works like a charm!! Thanks!